# Website does not recognise form input modified with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that extends a piece of software that I need to use for my work. I want to be able to copy all the form data from one page to another, but when I click save it immediately reverts to what it was before.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  //alert(e.which);
  if (e.shiftKey && ( e.which === 67 )) {
    var inputs = $("input[type|='text'], select");
    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
      var id = $(inputs[i]).attr("id");
      var val = $(inputs[i]).val();

      if(id != undefined && id.indexOf("rmaAssetComponents") != -1)
      {
        id = id.split("_")[7];
      }

      writeCookie(id, val, 1);
    }
  }
  if (e.shiftKey && ( e.which === 86 )) {
    var inputs = $("input[type|='text'], select");
    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
      var val = $(inputs[i]).val();
      var id = $(inputs[i]).attr("id");
      var searchId = id;

      if(id != undefined && id.indexOf("rmaAssetComponents") != -1)
      {
        searchId = id.split("_")[7];
        //console.log(searchId);
      }

      if(val == '')
      {
        $("[id*='"+id+"']").val(readCookie(searchId));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I know the code is spaghetti, please don't judge me too much. The gist is that I am storing the values of text inputs in cookies and then copying them using the .val() jquery function. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**
So it seems that the only inputs that it messes up on are editable dropdown menues. Not sure why still.

Comment: Cut down the code to be barebones enough to demonstrate the issue. Also make a JSFiddle.

Comment: It is very likely that the forms you are copying the data into rely on change events and those events are probably not getting triggered if they were not attached with jQuery. Try triggering a change event on each input right after you  set it's value.

Comment: Well I won't be able to reproduce the issue because it is operating on a website that isn't mine, and I don't feel comfortabe posting code that is possibly proprietary. I know it isn't a lot to work with, but any info would be helpful.

Comment: gforce301, I tried using a .trigger("change") but it doesn't seem to have an effect. I don't use js very much, so if that isn't the right way to do this please correct me.

Comment: Can you post some sample form html that triggers the problem?

Answer (score 0):

using .trigger() is a jQuery function, which straight javascript (which is what it appears you're using) won't recognize. Instead, you have the option of dispatchEvent() -- take a look **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)** to see what that's about.

What you're going to want to do is to create a new change event, and dispatch that on the changed field. Programmatic changes don't propagate the way user-entered changes do.

Comment: I am using jQuery.